# DeMorgan's Law Simplification

Tags: demorgans-law

I was wondering how to solve this question, which I'm told should be done with DeMorgan's Law.

```
M = X*(BAR(Y + Z)) + (X + BAR(Y))*(X + BAR(Z))
```

I am supposed to find a sum of products.

**EDIT:** The link for the identities can be found here [De Morgan Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Engineering)

Comment: if you go to wikipedia and type in demorgans law you can see the identitys, DeMorgans Law has two specific ones

Comment: Perhaps you are looking at a different page to us? Why not share the link in your question?

Comment: Is `BAR` the complement? What are those operators supposed to be? There is no addition and multiplication in either set theory or logic.

Comment: OOps sorry http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws#Engineering

Comment: scroll down to engineering section for the identities

Comment: @poke BAR is the line across Y+Z, see the link i posted

Comment: @user91208 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23321/is-it-appropriate-to-comment-on-peoples-accept-rate

Answer (score 2):

You can use de Morgan or you can just get it directly form the truth table:

```
X Y Z   M

0 0 0   1
0 0 1   0
0 1 0   0
0 1 1   0
1 0 0   1
1 0 1   1
1 1 0   1
1 1 1   1
```

So:

```
M = X+(Y+Z)'
```

Answer (score 1):

I’m going to use the mathematical symbols, `∨` for *or*, `∧` for *and*, and `¬` for *not*.

```
M = X ∧ ( ¬( Y ∨ Z ) ) ∨ ( X ∨ ¬Y ) ∧ ( X ∨ ¬Z )
  ⇔ X ∧ ( ¬Y ∧ ¬Z ) ∨ ( X ∨ ¬Y ) ∧ ( X ∨ ¬Z )
  ⇔ ( X ∧ ( ¬Y ∧ ¬Z ) ) ∨ ( ( X ∨ ¬Y ) ∧ ( X ∨ ¬Z ) )
  ⇔ ( X ∧ ¬Y ∧ ¬Z ) ∨ ( X ∨ ( ¬Y ∧ ¬Z ) )
  ⇔ ( X ∧ ¬Y ∧ ¬Z ) ∨ X ∨ ¬( Y ∨ Z )
  ⇔ X ∨ ¬( Y ∨ Z )
```

The last line can be done because `X ∧ ¬Y ∧ ¬Z => X` whereas `X` alone evaluates `M` to `true`, so that operand is not necessary.

Comment: Nice - and the result matches mine derived form a truth table, which is comforting.

Comment: how do you go from  line 3 to line 4. I thought on line 3: ( ( X ∨ ¬Y ) ∧ ( X ∨ ¬Z ) ) 
= ( ( X ∧ X ) ∨ ( X ∧ ¬Y ) ∨ ( X ∧ ¬Z ) ∨( X ∧ ¬Z ))
= ( X ∨ ( X ∧ ¬Y ) ∨ ( X ∧ ¬Z ) ∨( X ∧ ¬Z ))

Comment: That’s because logical OR and AND are [distributive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Rule_of_replacement). So `(A ∨ B) ∧ (A ∨ C)` is equivalent with `A ∧ (B ∨ C)`. You seem to expand `(X ∨ ¬Y)` to `X ∨ (X ∧ ¬Y)`, which is not the same as `X` does not need to be true, so `¬Y` is actually important for the result. And in the second part, you just repeat the `(X ∧ ¬Z)` once more which won’t do anything.